# IEnumerable<XElement> and foreach

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I would like to select all elements of a

```
var q = from artikel in xmlSource.Descendants("ART")
    where artikel.Element("ID").Value.Equals("15")
    select artikel.Elements();

 //Does not work
 foreach (var element in q)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Customer name = {0}", element.Name);
 }
```

How can I output all elements? I have some problems with iterators.

I don't now how to iterate a 
    IEnumerable 
with foreach and access the element.Name property.

//********* Aditional Information //

Example XML

```
<ARTICLE>
  <ART>
    <ID>0020209</ID>
    <EXP>36</EXP>
    <QTY>1</QTY>
    <SMCAT>B</SMCAT>
    <DSCRD>Example Description 1</DSCRD>
    <ARTCOMP>
      <COMPNO>10710</COMPNO>
      <ROLE>H</ROLE>
      <ARTNO1>320059</ARTNO1>
      <ARTNO2>320059</ARTNO2>
    </ARTCOMP>
    <ARTCOMP>
      <COMPNO>10710</COMPNO>
      <ROLE>V</ROLE>
      <ARTNO1>320059</ARTNO1>
      <ARTNO2>320059</ARTNO2>
    </ARTCOMP>
    <ARTBAR>
      <CDTYP>E13</CDTYP>
      <BC>7680202580475</BC>
      <BCSTAT>A</BCSTAT>
    </ARTBAR>
    <ARTPRI>
      <VDAT>2010-12-01T00:00:00+01:00</VDAT>
      <PTYP>PEXF</PTYP>
      <PRICE>30</PRICE>
    </ARTPRI>
  </ART>
  <ART>
    <ID>0020244</ID>
    <EXP>60</EXP>
    <QTY>30</QTY>
    <DSCRD>FERRO GRADUMET Depottabl 30 Stk</DSCRD>
    <ARTCOMP>
      <COMPNO>1836</COMPNO>
      <ROLE>H</ROLE>
      <ARTNO1>685230</ARTNO1>
      <ARTNO2>685230</ARTNO2>
    </ARTCOMP>
    <ARTCOMP>
      <COMPNO>1836</COMPNO>
      <ROLE>V</ROLE>
      <ARTNO1>685230</ARTNO1>
      <ARTNO2>685230</ARTNO2>
    </ARTCOMP>
    <ARTCOMP>
      <COMPNO>5360</COMPNO>
      <ROLE>L</ROLE>
      <ARTNO1>685230</ARTNO1>
      <ARTNO2>685230</ARTNO2>
    </ARTCOMP>
  </ART>
</ARTICLE>
```

I have to import this XML File into a normalized MySQL Table. ARTCOMP / ARTBAR are additional tables in the MySQL Datebase.

As a beginning, I wanted to create all the fields as varchar() in an empty MySQL Table. As an additional problem, not every ART element has the same child elements. Maybe there is a better way of finding all possible child elements (kind of schema).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your `foreach`, more likely it is your query not returning any elements. Try examining `q` in the debugger. What does it contain ?

Comment: @driis: Nope, the given code wouldn't compile. `Name` isn't a property of `IEnumerable<XElement>`...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `select` clause means that the type of `q` is actually `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<XElement>>`. I suspect you mean:

```
var q = from artikel in xmlSource.Descendants("ART")
        where artikel.Element("ID").Value.Equals("15")
        from element in artikel.Elements()
        select element;
```

Or:

```
var q = from artikel in xmlSource.Descendants("ART")
        where (string) artikel.Element("ID") == "15"
        from element in artikel.Elements()
        select element;
```

or even:

```
var q = from artikel in xmlSource.Descendants("ART")
        where (int) artikel.Element("ID") == 15
        from element in artikel.Elements()
        select element;
```

That will give a type for `q` of just `IEnumerable<XElement>` - it will flatten the results, basically. You'll get a sequence of *all* elements which are directly beneath an element called "ART" which in turn has an "ID" element of with a value of 15.

If that's not what you're looking for, please give more information - ideally a sample XML file along with your expected output.

It seems unlikely that you *really* want to print the element name of all the elements though... the customer name should be stored as a *value* somewhere (either text within the element or an attribute), not as the element name.

EDIT: If you *want* to use an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<XElement>>` you can use:

```
foreach (var result in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Next result...");
    foreach (var element in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got name: {0}", element.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note the use of the cast `(int)  artikel.Element("ID") == 15` - that is one of the very nice touches on the XLinq API: it attempts to cast the `Value` property to the type without needing to access the `Value` property and dealing with an exception if it is not present. Furthermore, you can cast to `int?` and if the element is not there, `null` will be returned, allowing you to tolerate missing nodes without burdensome checking.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.

As you stated in the post, the type of q is IEnumerable<IEnumerable<XElement>>.

If I inspect the variable q in the debugger, I see a lot of results.

My problem is, that I don't know how to iterate through the result with for each. My goal is to find out all names of all elements. For each element name I have to create a field in a MySQL table.

My problem is, that I don't know how to handle IEnumerable<IEnumerable<XElement>> and iterate them.

Comment: @Brainski: Okay, If you *want* it to be an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<XElement>>`, that's easy enough to deal with. I'll edit...